# Bootable + system backup hard drive

Tags: windows-10, backup, bootable-media

I installed windows 10 from an external hard drive. Just now I also saved the system image backup on the same drive.

Is there any problem with this ? Can I still boot and do stuffs like repair on this drive (like before) as well as recover my data from this same drive ?

Comment: I haven't understand your question: you have an external hard drive, right? Then you install windows 10 on the internal / other hard drive, right? And on which drive have you saved  the system image backup? I would think, on the external one?

Comment: yes, the external one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, adding extra files should be fine. Just don't change the existing files. When in recovery mode you can browse to the image and restore.